# R - regexp in each string of a table of char

Tags: regex, r

I would like to make a regex operation at each string of an array.
For instance, take the first characters of each string before a '-'. The results will be store in another array.

```
('Hello-1','Hi-2','Hola-3')
```

will give

```
('Hello','Hi','Hola')
```

Is there a way do do it in R without a loop ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide examples of sample input and expected output. And please do not change the question: now, you want this, then, you want something else. That is not a proper way to ask questions on SO.

Comment: This is a different question now `sub('-.*', '', str1)`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the question that was badly asked at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the updated question, we can match the character '-' followed by one or more characters until the end of the string and replace with `''`.

```
sub('-.*$', '', test)
```

Comment: @sandoval31 Can you show an example data that doesn't work?

Comment: @ akrun. Thanks for you two answers. substr(str1, 1, 3) is perfect for length defined strings, and sub('-.*', '', str1) works with a delimiter.